# How to avoid colors mixing up between two plot types in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following result:

[image: current plot]

It's a `plt.scatter` with `plt.bar` on top of it.

For some reason, the bar chart is being colored, but I want it to be of a specific color which is not part of the colors used by the scatter plot. How do I achieve that?

My current code:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure

def scatter_plot_from_to_delta(start, end, title="Delta times per day"):
  filtered = OrderedDict()

  # Generating filrered score dict (K=participant, V=list of each day's delta, with 0 as filtered out) 
  for name in names:
    score = list()
    for delta in scores.get(name):
      if delta > end or delta < start:
        delta = 0
      score.append(delta)
    filtered[name] = score

  figure(figsize=(20, 11)) # size of the whole graph

  # Preparing data for listed participants
  listed = OrderedDict() # (K=name displayed in the graph, V=amount of times displayed)
  latest_listed_day = 1 # ends up determining the last X axis value in the graph
  for key, value in filtered.items():
    listed[key] = dict()
    listed[key]['amnt'] = 0
    x = list()
    y = list()
    for i, val in enumerate(value):
      if val != 0:
        x.append(i+1)
        latest_listed_day = max(i+1, latest_listed_day)
        y.append(val)
        listed[key]['amnt'] += 1
    if listed[key]['amnt'] == 0:
      del listed[key]
    else:
      listed[key]['x'] = x
      listed[key]['y'] = y
  ordered_counter = OrderedDict(sorted(listed.items(), reverse=True, key=lambda item: item[1]['amnt']))
  print(ordered_counter)

  # Scatter plot
  for key, value in ordered_counter.items():
    x = value['x']
    y = value['y']
    plt.scatter(x, y, s=200) # s=size of the dots
    for i, _ in enumerate(x):
      plt.annotate(key, (x[i]+0.15, y[i]-0.27)) # marking names by each dot

  # Bar chart for the amount of listed participants on each day
  for i in range(num_challenges-1):
    participants_listed_that_day = 0
    for _, val in filtered.items():
      s = val[i]
      if s != 0:
        participants_listed_that_day += 1
    if participants_listed_that_day != 0:
      plt.bar(i+1, participants_listed_that_day)
      # Displaying the total per day above each bar
      plt.text(i+0.908,
              participants_listed_that_day+0.15,
              str(participants_listed_that_day),
              fontsize=18)

  # Concatenate (sorted) amount of times displayed for more info in legend
  displayed = list()
  for key, value in ordered_counter.items():
    concat = "(" + str(value['amnt']) + ") " + key
    displayed.append(concat)

  # Legend of listed participants
  plt.legend(displayed,
             scatterpoints=11,
             loc='center left',
             bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5),
             ncol=1,
             fontsize=16)

  plt.xticks(range(1,latest_listed_day+1)) # ensure x axis tick for every day
  plt.xlim((0.5,latest_listed_day+1.5)) # force displayed x range

  plt.title(title, fontsize=30)
  plt.xlabel("Day")
  plt.ylabel("Delta (in seconds)")
  plt.show()
```

Comment: do you want your bars to have one solid color or different colors than the colors used in the scatter plot?

Comment: One color used for all the bars, which isn't used by any of the dots in the scatter plot.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose two discrete or qualitative [colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) that have distinct colors from each other (and also enough colors to exceed the number of categories in your data), such as `tab10` and `tab20b`, then update the scatter plot and bar chart portions of your function.

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm

# Scatter plot
for key, value in ordered_counter.items():
  x = value['x']
  y = value['y']

  plt.scatter(x, y, s=200, cmap=cm.tab10) # s=size of the dots
  for i, _ in enumerate(x):
    plt.annotate(key, (x[i]+0.15, y[i]-0.27)) # marking names by each dot

# Bar chart for the amount of listed participants on each day
for i in range(num_challenges-1):
  participants_listed_that_day = 0
  for _, val in filtered.items():
    s = val[i]
    if s != 0:
      participants_listed_that_day += 1
  if participants_listed_that_day != 0:
    cmap_tab20b = plt.get_cmap("tab20b")
    rescale = lambda y: (y - np.min(y)) / (np.max(y) - np.min(y))
    plt.bar(i+1, participants_listed_that_day, color=cmap_tab20b(rescale(participants_listed_that_day)))
    # Displaying the total per day above each bar
    plt.text(i+0.908,
            participants_listed_that_day+0.15,
            str(participants_listed_that_day),
            fontsize=18)
```

Comment: This seems to throw `TypeError: object of type 'ListedColormap' has no len()` when it reaches `plt.bar`

Comment: I think I must have incorrectly passed the argument `color=cm.tab20b`, let me know if the updated answer works better

Comment: Now there is no more error, but the bars are invisible. And I see no difference in the colors of the scattered dots.